# Добавление <input> в зависимости от выбора <select>

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```js
const authorNameLabel = document.createElement('div');
authorNameLabel.innerHTML = '<lable for="main-name">Фамилия автора</lable> <input name="main-name" id="main-name"/><lable>  Инициалы</lable> <input /> </br></br>'

function runSelect() {
  const numberOfAuthors = document.querySelector('#number-of-authors').value;
  switch (numberOfAuthors) {
    case '1':
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      break;
    case '2':
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      break;
    case '7':
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      }
      break;
    case 'more-then-8':
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      }
      authorNameLabel.innerHTML = '<lable for="main-name">Фамилия ПОСЛЕДНЕГО автора</lable> <input name="main-name" id="main-name"/><lable>  Инициалы</lable> <input /> </br></br>'
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      break;
    case 'organisation':
      authorNameLabel.innerHTML = '<lable for="main-name">Название организации, учреждения, что подготовила монографию <input name="main-name" id="main-name"/> </br></br>'
      authorList.appendChild(authorNameLabel);
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-window">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form action="">
      <div id="authorList"><label>Количество авторов</label>
        <select id="number-of-authors" name="number-of-authors" onchange="runSelect()">
          <option value="1"> 1 автор </option>
          <option value="2"> 2 автори </option>
          <option value="7"> от 3 до 7 авторов </option>
          <option value="more-then-8"> больше 8 авторов </option>
          <option value="organisation"> Автор неизвестен або колективный автор (учереждение) </option>
        </select>
        </br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь добавить в модальное окно форму на js. В зависимости от того, что выберет пользователь в select, ниже должен добавится div с нужными input. 
Что ни пробовала, создается только один div, более того, когда выбираю 1 автор, совсем не создается ничего, когда последнее (автор неизвестен) то потом не меняется уже на другое, что бы ни выбирала (((

Подскажите, плиз, где ошибка, может логика неправильная.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите такой вариант:

```js
// Добавляем новый блок с классом tmp
function addBlock(html) {
  var authorNameLabel = document.createElement('div');
  authorNameLabel.className = "tmp";
  authorNameLabel.innerHTML = (html) ? html : '<lable for="main-name">Фамилия автора</lable> <input class="main-name" /><lable>Инициалы</lable></br></br>';
  return authorNameLabel;
}
// Очищаем старые блоки с классом tmp 
function removeBlocks() {
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.tmp');
  blocks.forEach(function(el){
    el.remove();
  });
}

var authorList = document.getElementById('authorList');
function runSelect() {
 removeBlocks();
 var numberOfAuthors = document.getElementById('number-of-authors').value;
 switch (numberOfAuthors) {
     case '1': authorList.appendChild(addBlock());
              
       break;
     case '2': authorList.appendChild(addBlock());
               authorList.appendChild(addBlock());
              
       break;
     case '7': for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
               authorList.appendChild(addBlock());
             }
       break;
     case 'more-then-8': for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                           authorList.appendChild(addBlock('<lable for="main-name">Фамилия ПОСЛЕДНЕГО автора</lable> <input name="main-name"/><lable>  Инициалы</lable>  </br></br>'));
                         }                      
                         break;
     case 'organisation': authorList.appendChild(addBlock('<lable for="main-name">Название организации, учреждения, что подготовила монографию <input name="main-name"/> </br></br>'));
       break;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-window">
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="">
    <div id="authorList"><label>Количество авторов</label>
    <select id="number-of-authors" name="number-of-authors" onchange="runSelect()">
      <option value="0" selected> Выбрать.. </option>
      <option value="1" > 1 автор </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 автора </option>
      <option value="7"> от 3 до 7 авторов </option>
      <option value="more-then-8"> больше 8 авторов </option>
      <option value="organisation"> Автор неизвестен или коллективный автор (учреждение) </option>
    </select></br></br>
    </div>
</form>
```

P.S. Не используйте одинаковый `id` у нескольких элементов, для объединения однотипных элементов в одну группу используйте атрибут `class`.

Comment: спасибо за идею с функциями  addBlock() и removeBlocks(). Правда, в последней я переписала цикл forEach на for, так как он не применяется к коллекциям (псевдомассивам). Но к ней дело не доходит, так как консоль выбивает ошибку, что не найдена функция runSelect() в html. Не ясно почему(((

Comment: да queryselectorall  возвращает NodeList, если нужен массив то можно так Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tmp')).forEach..., что касается ошибки, здесь данный код работает, если у вас всплывает ошибка значит где-то что-то у себя поменяли. Смотрите где именно возникает в консоле. Js скрипт в head подключили?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!